# creating a select tag with multiple options across multiple lines

Tags: html, css

So I have tried searching everywhere for this and I cant find a solution.

I am creating a recipe website as a hobby for myself, I have already got the JavaScript to let me select multiple items but I cant get the tags over one line.

so i want the options to display horizontally but once they have reached the overflow id like them to start a new row

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```css
 
select{
    display:table;
    width:inherit;
    }
option {
    display:table-cell;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #B2E0DF;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius:15px
}
```

```html
<div id="tags">
<select size="4" multiple>
<option value="Curry">Curry</option>
<option value="Italian">Italian</option>
<option value="Comfort">Comfort Food</option>
<option value="Gluten">GlutenFree</option>
<option value="onePot">onePot</option><br />
<option value="pasta">Pasta</option>
<option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
<option value="indian">Indian</option>
<option value="Korean">Korean</option>
<option value="BBQ">BBQ</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the options in a column or not on the same line, change display: table to display: flex. Also remove display: table-cell from the option tag in the CSS.